# Problemas con CV::Rectangle OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv

Tengo un problema a la hora de dibujar una rectángulo en un cv::mat. estoy realizando una comunicación entre Unity y C++ para generar una aplicación de Android.

Utilizo la cámara de Webcamtexture de unity y mando la información de a C++ utilizando el método PInvoke. Una vez en el código C++, quiero dibujar un rectángulo pero me sale mas de uno en la imagen (ver imagen) y realmente no entiendo el porqué. espero que podáis ayudarme. os adjunto el código de C++ y C#

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

C#

```
void Update()
{
    //texto.text = texto.text + " / "+ testo().ToString();
    imgData = null;
    imgData = new byte[width * height * 3];
    resultado = null;
    resultado = new byte[width * height * 3];
    color = webcam.GetPixels32();
    int bytesPerPixel = 3;
    const int indexR = 0;
    const int indexG = 1;
    const int indexB = 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < color.Length; i++)
    {
        imgData[(i * bytesPerPixel) + indexR] = color[i].r;
        imgData[(i * bytesPerPixel) + indexG] = color[i].g;
        imgData[(i * bytesPerPixel) + indexB] = color[i].b;
    }
    color = null;
    ProcessFrame(imgData, resultado, 0, 0, 0,0, nuevo);
    nuevo = false;
    textura2 = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    textura2.LoadRawTextureData(resultado);
    textura2.Apply();
    renderer.material.mainTexture = textura2;
    textura2 = null;
    Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
}
```

C++

```
void ProcessFrame(unsigned char* arr, unsigned char* resu,int posx, int posy, int poswidth, int posheight,bool nuevo) {
    Mat dst;//dst image
    trueRect.x = 150;
    trueRect.y = 150;
    trueRect.width = 100;
    trueRect.height = 100;
    wi = poswidth;
    he = posheight;
    mal = 20;
    dst = Mat(tamWid,tamHeid,CV_8UC3, arr);
    rectangle(dst, Point(50,50), Point(100,100), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 255));
    copy(dst.datastart, dst.dataend, resu);
}
```

Comment: no, es parte del codigo que he borrado, en principio eso no afecta. 

envio la informacion de la webcam en un byte[] de c# a c++ (unsigned char* arr) y devuelvo el resultado en unsigned char* resu.

Comment: a ver ahora, he añadido el codigo de C# igual puede ayudar

Comment: yo sigo sin ver nada raro... salvo que haces `textura2 = null` sin hacer antes un delete... ¿seguro que el problema no se encuentra en el código que has omitido? Yo probaría el ejemplo que estás poniendo a ver si reproduce el problema

Comment: Tiene pinta de que se lía con el ancho real de la imagen: Cada línea horizontal la dibuja en un sitio distinto, como si el offset fuese saltando: la arista superior (primera línea) la pone en el primer rectángulo, las siguientes líneas (un punto para cada arista vertical) las va repartiendo entre todas las posiciones que vemos, y la última línea aparece en la tercera posición.

Comment: Le paso la información del tamaño de la imagen en una función anterior, funciono con una resolución de 640x480. No entiendo exactamente que me quieres decir con arista, y mucho meno como podria silucionarlo.